# I need a fast delete of empty folders and sub folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am running a script that searches for empty directories and deletes them.

I moved it to a script (and call it from a c# process) as I wanted to avoid putting items into the recycle bin. The problem is that it is very slow.

This is my current script:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set TopLevel=%1    

rem process each folder contained in base folder
for /d %%t in ("%TopLevel%\*.*") do (
    echo Processing '%%~t' ...
    rem Remove any empty folders below this user folder
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /ad "%%t" ^| sort /r') do (rd /q "%%~i" >NUL
    )
)
```

so: @gerald I changed it to this:

@echo off
   setlocal

```
set TopLevel=%1

DEL /Q /F /S %2 >nul 2>&1

pushd "%~1" then for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%~a"
```

my directory structure is:

```
yyyy > mm > dd > hh > m1
                    > m2

      > mm1 > dd1 > hh1 > m3
```

so if delete m1 and m2  I would expect to see this left over:

```
yyyy > mm1 > dd1 > hh1 > m3
```

Comment: One thing you can do to make it go faster is remove the `echo` inside the loop

Comment: @AndrewSimpson please try not to tag questions with irrelevant tags, like C# for this one.  It has nothing to do with C#.  I came here thinking I could help with a C# problem, but the fact that you're calling it from a "C# process"  -- and you really mean a .NET process, or actually any executable, script, shortcut, or otherwise, because what does it matter what language was used to write it -- is superfluous.

Comment: @rory.ap Hi, I do apologize.  Lesson learnt :)

Comment: You could always write some C or C++ code and use the Batch script to call the compiled executable. That may be faster than doing the operation through batch (at least more portable).

Comment: @DrakeJohnson Hi it may come to that. Been years since I touched c++ :(

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I can write it for you if you'd like haha

Comment: OMG! would you? I would accept that as an answer. Biggest mistake i ever made moving from c/c++ to vb.net/C# :(

Comment: @KenWhite hah! I was playing along :)

Comment: Hoe about s single loop. You are using 2 which is an overkill. `pushd "%~1"` then `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%~a"`

Comment: This question belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @AndrewSimpson No, I was serious. I'm not going to make it an answer, but I will post a link to the code in a comment.

Comment: @AndrewSimpson Here you go! I have a pre-compiled exe file and an already written .bat file for you to use if you'd like. Also, there's the source code as well in case you want to do some tweaking. [Click here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/14-07ji_mBiGj89mi-o3-Eeo7Nh2doYtv?usp=sharing)

Comment: @DrakeJohnson OMG that’s so cool. I am out about at mo but will take a look when back. Thanks again

Comment: @GerhardBarnard thanks will try out when home :)

Comment: @GerhardBarnard just tried this out. No folders were deleted?